# JavaFX TableView custom cell color glitches when deleting item

Tags: java, javafx

Here is my the TableCell made by my CellFactory:

```
                @Override
            protected void updateItem(Void value, boolean empty) {
                if (empty) {
                    setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
                } else {
                    Fish fish = getTableRow().getItem();
                    if (fish == null) {
                        setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
                    } else {
                        setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + Utils.colorToString(fish.getColor()));
                    }
                }
            }
```

It works ok, but when I delete an item from the Table's items, it looks like this:

[image]

How can I stop those colors from appearing at the bottom? I have spent at least 10 hours looking for a solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using two different mechanisms to set the background: either setting a background directly with `setBackground(...)`, or setting the style.

If the style is set on a cell, and then the cell becomes empty, the style is not removed, so a background color remains.

Stick to either one or the other:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Void value, boolean empty) {
    if (empty) {
        setStyle("");
    } else {
        Fish fish = getTableRow().getItem();
        if (fish == null) {
            setStyle("");
        } else {
            setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + Utils.colorToString(fish.getColor()));
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Void value, boolean empty) {
    if (empty) {
        setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
    } else {
        Fish fish = getTableRow().getItem();
        if (fish == null) {
            setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
        } else {
            setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(fish.getColor(), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        }
    }
}
```